# setTimeout is not working when Windows goes to sleep mode and then wake up

Tags: javascript, windows

I have noticed this in Chrome. Has anyone an idea about what's wrong or a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` instead - it keeps on running. If you need a one-shot solution, use `clearInterval` to delete the timer. `setInterval` will fire immediately if the computer was asleep while the event should have been fired. I tested this behavior in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. As an example, have look at http://blaeul.de/de/content/javascript-timer-test and its source.

Answer (score 3):

When Chrome goes in the background it freezes JavaScript execution. I noticed this on drawings when it's minimized to the Dock in OS X.

---

There is no workaround as far as I know. If you tell us what you are trying to do there might be something that can be done.

Comment: I try to poll a server for new data ( new updates in the DB ) fetched every 10s with an ajax call. I don't know how gmail actually succeed to still making working when Windows wakes up.

Comment: @Dave: First off polling is *horrible* and should be a last resort. Try [WebSockets](http://joshuakehn.com/blog/view/2/WebSocket-Tutorial-with-Node-js). Also I would guess that Google puts some sort of check code that will recreate the interval.

Comment: @JoshK - Websocket support is not wide enough yet; and the more general Comet/long-poll approaches are not supported well by all webservers.