# How can I get new CSRF token in LARAVEL by using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have created a form which is having a lot of fields and user can create an unlimited field in it. 
If a user spends more time on it CSRF token get expires and when he clicks on the submit LARAVEL return the error CSRF token mismatch. 
So how can I get new CSRF token by using ajax call so I can update the CSRF on a regular time of interval?
I can not refresh or reload the form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling expired token in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449434/handling-expired-token-in-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
</script>
```

And make sure you have added token to your meta tag like below.

```
<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
```

I hope this will work for you.

Link https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

If you still found the same issue then please review these pieces of stuff

1. [Handling expired token in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449434/handling-expired-token-in-laravel)
2. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/csrf-token-mismatch-error-on-session-timeout-form?page=1

And Make sure you take a look at all answers, not only checked one

Comment: Yes  @Geoffrey. I just changed the name by my way

Comment: Actually, I am doing same but this key get expire after some time so I need new key without reloading page.

Comment: In that case, you might need to take a look at this stuff.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449434/handling-expired-token-in-laravel
2. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/csrf-token-mismatch-error-on-session-timeout-form?page=1. And Make sure you take a look on all answers, not only checked one.

Comment: Hey yes, Brain can you put this answer in the original answer so I can mark it as the correct solution. Thanks very much it was the easiest solution.

Comment: Added. @FIROZTENNALI

Answer (score 17):

**Update;** Although below answers what was asked for, but:

- All pages of `session` share the exact same CSRF-token (at least in Laravel),
- Hence if one browser-tab creates a new token,
- All other tabs suddenly have an invalid-token !!

### Old answer

By using this code you can get a new token after login by using the `regenerate()` method and returning a new `csrf_token()` in the response.

Your Controller inside the function:

```php
public function refreshToken(Request $request)
{
     session()->regenerate();
     return response()->json([
        "token"=>csrf_token()],
      200);

}
```

JavaScript:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "{{url('refresh-token')}}",
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content', result.token);
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': result.token
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I use this approach to load new CSRF Token on document ready with ajax to replace all tokens in static page from Laravel Cached Response.