# Laravel 5 Ajax 500 (Internal Server Error) when making a post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I keep getting this error "500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery.min.js:5ajax @ jquery.min.js:5(anonymous) @ (index):260dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3v.handle @ jquery.min.js:3" whenever i try making a post request using ajax in laravel and would realy appreciate some assistance.
Below is the code in my view:

```
    <form action="" >

    <div class="switch-field">
    <h5>Academic Level</h5>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="highschool" name="academic_level" value="Highschool" />
    <label for="highschool">High School</label>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="college" name="academic_level" value="College" />
    <label for="college">College</label>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="university" name="academic_level" value="University" />
    <label for="university">University</label>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="masters" name="academic_level" value="Masters" />
    <label for="masters">Master's</label>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="phd" name="academic_level" value="Phd" />
    <label for="phd">PhD</label>
    </div>

    <div class="switch-field">
    <h5>Spacing</h5>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="double_spaced" name="spacing" value="Double Spaced" />
    <label for="double_spaced">Double Spaced</label>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="single_spaced" name="spacing" value="Single Spaced" />
    <label for="single_spaced">Single Spaced</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <h5>No. of pages</h5>
    <input class="changedVal" type="number"  name="no_pages" min="1" max="10" value="1" />
    </div>

    <div class="switch-field" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    <h5>Deadline</h5>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="14_days" name="deadline" value="14 Days" />
    <label for="14_days">14 Days</label>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="7_days" name="deadline" value="7 Days" />
    <label for="7_days">7 Days</label>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="5_days" name="deadline" value="5 Days" />
    <label for="5_days">5 Days</label>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="3_days" name="deadline" value="3 Days" />
    <label for="3_days">3 Days</label>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="48_hrs" name="deadline" value="48 Hrs" />
    <label for="48_hrs">48 Hrs</label>
    <input class="changedVal" type="radio" id="24_hrs" name="deadline" value="24 Hrs" />
    <label for="24_hrs">24 Hrs</label>
    </div>

    <input style="margin-left:-300px;margin-top:0px;width:200px;border:none;background-color:transparent;font-size:30px;color:#32c5d2;" type="text" id="testVal">

    <script type="text/javascript" >
    var coun=0;

    $('.changedVal').change(function(){

    var level=$('input[name=academic_level]:checked').val();
    var spacing=$('input[name=spacing]:checked').val();
    var pages=$('input[name=no_pages]').val();
    var deadline=$('input[name=deadline]:checked').val();

    var data={academic_level:level,spacing:spacing,pages:pages,deadline:deadline};

    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
    url: '/pricecalculator',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    success: function(msg){

    console.log('data returned='+msg);

     $('#testVal').val(msg);
     }
     });
     });
     </script>

     </form>
```

The below code is my route:

```
    Route::post('/pricecalculator', array('uses' => 'MainController@priceCalculator'));
```

The below code is my controller:

```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\Http\Requests;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use App\Prices;
   use View;

   class MainController extends Controller
   {
   public function priceCalculator(Request $request)
   {
    $request->all();

    dd($request);
   }
   }
```

Comment: You need to send the csrf token in your header of your ajax call. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668337/how-can-i-get-new-csrf-token-in-laravel-by-using-ajax/45668376#45668376

Comment: Thanks mate...it worked

Comment: You welcome. Glad It helps

Answer (score 0):

When you are making a post request in laravel, than you must include the `csrf token` value in the ajax header like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'login',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        key: value
    },

    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success: function(response){

    }
});
```

in absence of this, you will get the **500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: Thanks...i was able to sort it