# Ajax calls return 419 error despite correct token in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a bunch of POST requests made with Ajax in my Laravel application.

A typical request looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/method',
    data: {'id': id},
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'JSON',
    success: function (response) {
        //handle data
    },
    error: function (response) {
        //handle error
    }
});
```

I have the CSRF token set and everything works fine most of the time:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
});
```

However, after a long hiatus (for example, computer asleep for a long time), all Ajax calls return a 419 error, as if the token wasn't set. After I reload the page everything is back to normal. This is on a local server.

How do I resolve this? Is there some way to "renew" the token before a call? Do I have to do the `$.ajaxSetup` bit before each call? It's not enough to do it once on page load?

Comment: You can handle that like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33631359/5447994)

Comment: @Thamilan There's really no better way to handle this than 1) extend session life and 2) show an error? The former approach doesn't really help if a user opens his laptop after a day or two, and the latter isn't very user-friendly.

Comment: If this is caused by session expiry at client/server side then you should check for session expiration in your front end using some kind of timer mechanism. When timer detect the session expiry and if your session is expired then logoff the user with some prompt. Also don't forget to reset session at client (server should be automatic) when user take some action on web page before session expiration time.

Comment: I don't think the csrf token is the way to go. I would implement the api token instead (not passport). This is a good starting point https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51

Comment: Trigger a page refresh as soon as you receive a 419.

Comment: This is simply because of security. You should not really want it to act any differently. However if you really want, you might want to use cookies and have those contain a special encrypted code which you can use to login the user. In case your 419 error comes along, you simply re-login the user with the use of the cookie.

Answer (score 4):

This is my suggestion:

**JS**

```
   //create a function to set header
    function setHeader(data){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN': data
             }
         });
    }
   //in first load of the page set the header
    setHeader($('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));

   //create function to do the ajax request cos we need to recall it when token is expire
    function runAjax(data){
      $.ajax({
         url: '/path/to/method',
         data: {'id': id},
         type: 'POST',
         datatype: 'JSON',
         success: function (response) {
            //handle data
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             if(jqXHR.status==419){//if you get 419 error which meantoken expired
                refreshToken(function(){refresh the token
                    runAjax();//send ajax again
                });
             }
         }
     });
    }

   //token refresh function
    function refreshToken(callback){
          $.get('refresh-csrf').done(function(data){
             setHeader(data);
              callback(true);
           });
    }
    //Optional: keep token updated every hour
     setInterval(function(){
            refreshToken(function(){
                    console.log("Token refreshed!");
                });

            }, 3600000); // 1 hour
```

**Route**

```
//route to get the token
Route::get('refresh-csrf', function(){
    return csrf_token();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The default implementation is Laravel is that if token expires, another auth session is required to create a new session token (i.e. redirect to login page). is something amiss?