# generate dynamic csrf-token for laravel SPA

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm using laravel 5.6 with axios and vue for my SPA web app.
the problem is after a while the csrf token will expire so there should be an annoying prompt telling the user to refresh the page which is not what I'm looking for.
so all I know about csrf token in laravel 5.6 is it's used in bootstrap.js in this way:

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
   window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
  console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x- 
  csrf-token');
}
```

how I change this to get the csrf token on each request?

Comment: The accepted answer to this question seems to be a decent implementation you could adopt to solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449434/handling-expired-token-in-laravel

Answer (score 3):

create an endpoint for retrieving the latest csrf token:

**ExampleController.php**

```
public function getCsrf() {
  return response(csrf_token());
}
```

**Route: (routes/wew.php)**

```
Route::get('csrf', 'ExampleController@getCsrf');
```

**In your Javascript, you can request for a new csrf token and replace the old one in your axios instance.**

```
axios.get('/csrf').then(({ data }) => {
  window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = data;
})
```

Comment: will that make the application less secured? The purpose of the CSRF is the generate a secret token by not exposing that to outside world, but via this API endpoint, the purpose becomes void! So something like an easy cake for an attacker isn't it?