# Laravel 8: to make an SPA never suffer from 419-error, is it appropriate to use Sanctum and put routes in api routes?

Tags: laravel

For the sake of making my use-case more understandable, I'll classify services like Figma, [WhatsApp](https://web.whatsapp.com/), etc as SPAs. I've never received a page-expired error from those "SPAs".

So it is 2020, and we now also have Laravel 8: is it appropriate to use Sanctum to achieve such never-expiring SPA just by placing all routes in api.php, assuming that the SPA is in the same domain/subdomain with the Laravel app?

Btw, according to the Sanctum docs, this implies the use of API tokens for those API routes, but this kind of usage for first-party SPA is clearly [not the intended use of Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication).

Comment: SPA you can achive by `vue-router` not in `api.php` or sanctum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Sanctum cannot handle this case, because if request is from the [frontend](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/4961787dcb82d17c77754ec69051168992b7fa57/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php#L56), it applies [session based auth checks](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/4961787dcb82d17c77754ec69051168992b7fa57/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php#L22-L34).

I have however [proposed a possible update that can make this possible](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/2454). Hopefully, it will be considered for implementation.

In the meantime, a sane workaround that does not pose any serious security threat for my use-case is to [increase the session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449434/handling-expired-token-in-laravel/58746758#58746758)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best way to achieve that but if it works you'll get your job done and I don't see the problem of making that even if it was intended for another use