# 419 Page Expired In Laravel Even after adding CSRF token

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-8, csrf

I am working on a Laravel 8 Framework,
I have added the application on the live Cpanel server and then it started showing below Error:

**419 PAGE EXPIRED**

I know generally missing CSRF token will be the main issue but in this, I have added the CSRF token,
I am using LARAVEl blade syntax so adding LARAVEL blade form syntax the "Token" (CSRF) will get added directly.

```
 {{ Form::open( [ "url" => \URL::route("front.login.check"), "autocomplete"=>false,"id" => "login_form" ] ) }}
```

This will add the CSRF automatically,
I have tried adding directly,
But every `POST` request end up on the `419 PAGE EXPIRED` page.

What do I have checked already?

- `CSRF Token` Is not missing in the `Form`
- I have checked middleware also but this request did not reach the middleware after form submit it will take to the `419` page
- Also try to `php artisan cache:clear` and `dump-autoload` command but the issue is still.
- Added **755** permission to `storage`, `vendor` and `cache` folder also.

Please help me on this **What next should I need to check for solve this issue?**

Comment: Does your session files `storage\framework\sessions\*` has `_token` key with value of 40 characters ?

Comment: @medilies yes sir this `sessions` file has `_token`
it's look like this  `a:2:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"A6TrQWNlZ7qckF7i4r0yiBwHqUD1Uvr4fRuyoUfp";s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}`

Comment: Your form should have a hidden input like `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="A6TrQWNlZ7qckF7i4r0yiBwHqUD1Uvr4fRuyoUfp">`

Comment: @medilies yes sir, as I mention I have a check that and `_token` is there. i have a double check on that.

Comment: It may be an issue with your session driver config. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31451983/17873304

Comment: @medilies try as your suggestion .. still on the same error page.. clear the config cache also

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Laravel "419 Page Expired" Error Troubleshooting Steps

***Apply/go through all steps up to "step 12" BEFORE testing your application for this error.***

1. Increase your [session expiration time](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/222908f96f7369fe5039d6cda4b84d15cacc1fb6/config/session.php#L34) (I.e. 24 hours).
2. Make sure that the "[session domain](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/222908f96f7369fe5039d6cda4b84d15cacc1fb6/config/session.php#L158)" is the **same as** the "app URL".
3. Ensure that the session [cookies are sent back to the server for both "HTTP" & "HTTPS" browser connections](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/222908f96f7369fe5039d6cda4b84d15cacc1fb6/config/session.php#L171).

**.env file contents applying the above 3 steps.**

Change *myapp.local* to your application domain.

```bash
APP_URL="http://myapp.local"
SESSION_LIFETIME=1440
SESSION_DOMAIN=myapp.local
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
```

4. Make sure you [submit a CSRF token](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests) along with your (`PUT`/`POST`/`DELETE`/etc.) HTTP requests.

- (I.e: Ensure that this request parameter is submitted along with your HTML form requests `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`).
- If in case you make AJAX requests in your application, you may configure ALL AJAX requests to send the CSRF token at all times.

  - Add this "`<meta>` tag" inside the `<head>` tag of all your master VIEW templates/layouts. I.e: **resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php** and **resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php** and **resources/views/welcome.blade.php**

    - `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`
  - Then, define the required HTTP request headers and recompile your app's static assets (`npm run dev`). **resources/js/app.js**

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
});
```

5. Regenerate your [application key](https://tighten.com/blog/app-key-and-you/) automatically. (I.e: `php artisan key:generate`).
6. Clear your application cache. (I.e: `php artisan cache:clear`).
7. Confirm that the application caller has *read & write* permissions in the application's "sessions" & "cache" folder. (I.e: `chmod -R 755 storage && chmod -R 755 "storage/framework/sessions" && chmod -R 755 "bootstrap/cache"`).

#### Addendum 1:

8. If in case you have [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#introduction) installed and enabled, add your application domain among the whitelist of "sanctum stateful domains".

**.env file contents**

Change *myapp.local* to your application domain.

```bash
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="myapp.local"
```

#### Addendum 2:

9. Ensure that your "session driver" isn't empty. [The default value is "file"](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/222908f96f7369fe5039d6cda4b84d15cacc1fb6/config/session.php#L21).

**.env file contents**

```bash
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

#### Addendum 3:

10. [Disable the browser cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/7376590). This may be beneficial during your development process.
11. Open your web browser, navigate to your application's home page, reload the current page, ignoring cached content. (I.e: On **Windows**: `Shift + F5` or `Ctrl + Shift + r`  and on **Mac**: `⌘ + Shift + r`).
12. **TEST YOUR APP!** Check if you still receive the error.

#### Addendum 4 (Optional):

***Only perform the steps below if you reached step 12 and are still having the same error.***

A. [Clear ALL web browser cache & cookies](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). **TEST YOUR APP!**

B. Open an entirely different web browser and test again. If you've been using [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/?brand=CHBD&brand=CHBD&gclid=Cj0KCQiAq5meBhCyARIsAJrtdr4yw8cAx9GR118VHlJpKA4BTwBGi_QWwFGD2svv0yoWRGwVESLqp8oaAshrEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) / [Safari](https://support.apple.com/downloads/safari) all along, try testing using [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/). **TEST YOUR APP!**

C. Restart your computer and test again. **TEST YOUR APP!**

Comment: I have checked each step you have given here, but still no luck
I have updated env, remove the cache also after each change but still stuck at the same error page

Comment: @always-a-learner Please try out the steps in **Addendum 4** of my edited answer.

Comment: SESSION_DRIVER=file fixes my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Just a word of warning, following the steps above, as soon as I reset the application key (php artisan key:generate), the problem I had of expired session became application-wide and I could no longer login.

Comment: "Confirm that the application caller has read & write permissions" that was my issue, and I solved it with https://stackoverflow.com/a/45673457/5248391

Comment: step 2 Worked..! Thanks.. Spent hours to solve the problem..

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen when you have the **SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE** flag set to **true** and then your request is made under an unsecure connection for example you access your application over http://yourdomain.com instead of https://yourdomain.com. The set-cookie header will be blocked because its received under an unsecure connection hence leading to the above session problem.

Answer (score -1):

This may be an edge case, but if you're using the database driver and something other than normal incrementing IDs for your user IDs (i.e, ULIDs or UUIDs), make sure the `user_id` field in the `sessions` table reflects the correct format for your user IDs.

Answer (score -4):

When this happened to me it was because I forgot to add 'name' attribute to my input in the form