# Laravel 10: 419 Page Expired despite CSRF in place

Tags: php, laravel

I have a large Laravel application (Laravel 10, PHP 8.1), recently due to a hosting issue I had to redeploy the whole thing from a backup, everything is working fine *except* if I need to submit any forms (which were working fine previously).

The @CSRF token is in place on the forms (and these worked fine previously).  Following the steps here ([419 Page Expired In Laravel Even after adding CSRF token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540756/419-page-expired-in-laravel-even-after-adding-csrf-token)), I have tried:

- Double checked the APP_URL settings
- Extended the SESSION_LIFETIME
- Added the SESSION_DOMAIN=myapp.local to .env
- Resetting permissions on the cache
- Updating the application
- Checked that the CSRF is generating the correct hidden field in the form
- Regenerated my application key
- Clear all the caches
- Switched the SESSION storage from file to database
- Completely binned my browsers cache, used incognite mode and a complete different browser.

Comment: Any suggestions for things to check would be great, for example, I can see the CSRF token in the HTML (for example, <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="BWgY6C304m1234567890gqSQ1IiUxKfCT"> but I have no idea where to check for this.  Should this bein the sessions table in the database?

Comment: Seems like you have tried most of the recommended things. Can you try to php artisan view:clear ?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, alas tried that too.   Much to my great shame, I didn't notice that for some reason, even though I logged in with https, the user is redirected to a http version fo the site once logged in!!!

Comment: Nice to see you solved it, small stuff like these can eat up a lot of time heh

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone else, this was my own lack of attention to detail.
For some reason on redeploying, users were being directed to a http version of the site (even though they logged in to the https version and the .ENV file and everything I can find say https).  Going to diagnose this new problem.